# How can i get Page Manager to load a new page.tpl.php file and override the current one?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I’ve created a new layout (.tpl.php) and is complete with an .info file.  It contains a region I call a super_footer. I want this to load only on certain content types and I’ve been attempting to use Page Manager to do this. I want to load some View Panes that use contextual filters into this super_footer.

Can’t I use Page Manager to do this? and shouldn’t I be able to get this new layout to load via Variants->Layout tab?

Comment: i was just looking again at PM and maybe i could reword the question to ask,..instead of variant type of panel, is there a way to do variant type of page?

Comment: I'm not sure you can load a different page template but you should be able to use your layout with over ridding the theme regions and use your own in your layout. Then template your other pieces with using template overrides find out more here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1678810

Comment: If you are using Drupal 7.33+ there is a new theme debug option you could use also, see: https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656 for more information.